# how to inject datasource into testng method execution listener

Tags: java, spring, testng, spring-test

I have a Method level listener in that looks like this

```
   public class DefaultListener implements IInvokedMethodListener2 {
       @Autowired
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;        

        public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        }

        public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        }

        public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult,
                ITestContext context) {
           updateDatabaseWithTestStartTime();           
        }
        private void updateDatabaseWithTestStartTime() {
           jdbcTemplate.update("....");
        }

        // other methods.
}
```

How do I autowire jdbcTemplate in the above example? I looked at spring-test and integration with test-ng, but examples like [these](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-spring-integration-example/), are talking about controlling autowiring at test level - My needs are listener specific.

Comment: The listener is not managed by spring container, why do you need it to autowire?

Comment: Testng is working out of box with Guice, but even with this integration it is not possible to inject into listeners. You need to find another way to find the object reference you want.

Comment: as you can see, I would like to hit the database and write some data to it. In order to write to database, I have to use data access layer (DAOs), which is a shared project that already has @Autowired jdbc template. So, I have to initialize spring to be able to autowire the data access layer.

Comment: Ok, so here's what I did so far. Inside onStart(ISuite) method of ISuiteListener, I initiated an application context using this code - new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:spring-context.xml");" How do I now make this context available to my IInvokedMethodListener?

Answer (score 2):

`IInvokedMethodListener2` is a TestNG listener and as such has nothing to do with the *Spring TestContext Framework*.

If you want to interact with beans in your Spring `ApplicationContext` in a reusable *listener*, you will therefore need to implement a Spring `TestExecutionListener`.

Take a look at the [`SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java) for inspiration on how to implement such a listener.

For further details, read all discussions regarding "`TestExecutionListener`" in the [Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing) chapter of the Spring reference manual, paying special attention to the [TestExecutionListener configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tel-config) section.